# Plotting points while plotting vectors : Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I need to make a plot with only points and tried something like

```
plot(x,y)
```

where `x` and `y` are vectors: collection of points.

I do not want matlab to connect these points itself. I want to plot as if plotted with

```
for loop
plot;hold on;
end
```

I tried

```
plot(x,y,'.');
```

But this gave me too thick points.

I do not want to use forloop because it is time expensive. It takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there, just change the MarkerSize property:

```
plot(x,y,'.','MarkerSize',1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
plot(x,y,'*');
```

or

```
plot(x,y,'+');
```

You can take a look to the documentation: http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/creating_plots/using-high-level-plotting-functions.html

Answer (score 2):

help scatter

IIRC:  where S is the size of the scatter points:
scatter(x,y,S)

Answer (score 1):

You may try this piece of code that avoid using loops. The plot created does not have lines but markers of different colors corresponding to each column of matrices `x` and `y`.

```
%some data (matrix)
x = repmat((2:10)',1,6);
y = bsxfun(@times, x, 1:6);

set(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder', jet(6)); %set the default matlab color 

figure('Color','w');
plot(x,y,'p'); %single call to plot
axis([1 11 0 70]);
box off;
legend(('a':'f')');
```

This gives

[image]